How to turn on my TV and video projector using an IR adapter through a Python interface on my PC?
I have a couple of LG TVs, model 65UR8750PSA and Benq projectors model MW560 but I want to turn these devices on and off via an IR adapter using a Python interface on my PC. I have researched some IR adapters such as FLIRC USB but I am not sure if you can help me make sure which adapter will work properly for this project.

what is the actual question? ... right now, your question is similar to how to build a race car?

Note that if you want to control them separately (rather than just turn everything on at the same time), you will probably need (at least) two separate transmitters, at least one for each TV, correctly targeted at the respective TV IR receiver, and possibly another one for the projector if it uses the same protocol or overlapping signals with the TVs. There are IR transmitters that are designed to be stuck directly on the TV's receiver (search for "IR Blaster"), and connected to an audio jack. There may also be alternative ways of controlling the TVs, via HDMI, Ethernet or Bluetooth.

The FLIRC USB claims that it will work with any remote. And it probably will. You have well known brands of TV and Projector, so it will almost certainly work.
If you want a guarantee then you should ask their support.
